# Is there more than one caret in JavaFX TextField?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, textfield

I'm currently getting in touch with JavaFx. As a starter, I try to write a small calculator.

This calculator contains a TextField showing the expression to be calculated. I am able to put text in there via keyboard or via the buttons of the calculator. Clicking into the TextField with the mouse or navigating via keyboard results in a blinking caret at the right position as expected. But this caret is obviously not backed by the caret property of the TextField, as `textField.getCaretPosition();` returns 0 no matter were the blinking "mouse/keyboard-caret" shows up. Moving the "intern" caret with `textField.forward()` or `textField.backward()` etc. works just fine.

Is there another property for the "mouse/keyboard-caret"? Please don't tell me I have to listen for mouseclicks and set the caret by myself. The same problem seems to occour for selections, `textField.getSelection()` returns (0,0), although text is selected(which means, it's blue).

Here's what I'm trying to do in my controller-class. textField.getText() works fine, so the TextField itself should not be the problem.

```
@FXML
private void onNumberButtonClicked(ActionEvent event){
    String formerText = textField.getText();
    int pos = textField.getCaretPosition(); //always returns 0, no matter were the cursor is
    String additionalText = ((Button)event.getSource()).getText();
    textField.setText(formerText.substring(0, pos) + 
    additionalText + 
    formerText.substring(pos));
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Quickly checked the source code, but it looks like the caretPosition is updated when a selection is made.

Comment: Thats quite reassuring. In this case the question is: What am I doing wrong? There not enough code in there for a big mistake...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The caret position is set to `0` when the `TextField` looses focus. When you click a button, it gets the focus, therefore the `TextField` looses it. You can store the old carret position when the control looses focus to fix this:

```
private int oldCaretPosition;
```

```
textField.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (!newValue) {
        oldCaretPosition = textField.getCaretPosition();
    }
});
```

```
private void onNumberButtonClicked(ActionEvent event){
    String formerText = textField.getText();
    String additionalText = ((Button)event.getSource()).getText();
    textField.setText(formerText.substring(0, oldCaretPosition)
                        + additionalText
                        + formerText.substring(oldCaretPosition));
}
```

Alternatively you can set [the `focusTraversable` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusTraversableProperty) of the `Button` to `false`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would never have thought of this. Works now :)